# Symfony route path /config - is it reserved?

Tags: symfony, routes

when i try to add route with path /config, it shows 404 not found. Strange thing is that its not regular 404 symfony error that shows when i enter non existing route Here is apache access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2015:11:32:26 +0100] "GET /config HTTP/1.1" 404 499 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2015:11:35:00 +0100] "GET /configasd HTTP/1.1" 404 743 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2015:11:36:42 +0100] "GET /configasdasd HTTP/1.1" 404 743 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0"
```

You can see that accessing /config generates 404 499 error code while accessing another non existing route generates 404 743 error code.

**My question is:** is "config" an reserved word for using in routes ? Is there an complete list of such words in symfony ?

EDIT: Route configuration:
in app/config/routing.yml:

```
myapp_config:
resource: "@MyappConfigBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /config
```

in MyappConfigBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
myapp_config:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: MyappConfigBundle:Config:index }
```

Comment: How do you declare this route?

Comment: Do you see the route using `router:debug` in console ?

Comment: doesn't have much time for digging it, but later ill do - based on comments I assume that 'config' isn't reserved word and should work fine as any other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status code for response is only 404, 499 and 743 - are sizes of response.

Your server is configured to have at `/config` path some other resource. It may be configured with some global alias or you can just have file/folder or symlink/hardlink with name `config` in your `web` directory.

Check all the cases and you will solve your problem.